# Get the value of query string

Tags: php, codeigniter-url

http://www.example.com/ci_admin_jaspud/index.php/admin/add_member/id/7/created_sort/asc

> how can i get the value of multiple query strings in above url using codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

URI class is loaded automatically and you can use the segment() method to retrieve the data

```
$this->uri->segment(4)
```

to get the 7

More info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->load->library('uri');
echo $this->uri->segment(4);
```

The URI Class provides functions that help you retrieve information from your URI strings.

[Codeigniter URI class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: Actually URI is no helper but a core class, there is a URL helper but isn't required for this.